# android view.findViewById and activity.findViewById, one cannot show the data

Tags: android

I've got a problem between `view.findViewById` and `activity.findViewById`.
Consisely it's when I use `view.findViewById` the data will not show and have no error report at all. And when I use the `activity.findViewById` , everything is fine. I dont know why or if I have made any mistake. Please give me some sugguestions.

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewManager viewManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewManager=new ViewManager(this);
        viewManager.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

ViewManger Code

```
public class ViewManager {
    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    ViewManager(AppCompatActivity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }
    public void setText(String text){
        //in this way the word"hello" cannot be shown
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        TextView textView=view.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        //this way it works but i dont know why i m wrong above
        //TextView textView=activity.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        textView.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a separate view hierarchy which has no link with your activity layout so nothing will happen on screen

so you can set `view` reference as `activity`'s layout

```
public void setText(String text){
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
    activity.setContentView(view);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TextView textView=view.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    //this way it works but i dont know why i m wrong above
    //TextView textView=activity.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    textView.setText("hello");
}
```

and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` no longer be needed

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the text on a view in a layout that you do not show. Once you inflated `R.layout.activity_main` in `ViewManger`, you never add the view to the one that got inflated by the activity itself (the layout passed as a parameter to `setContentView`). The reason that it works with activity is that in that case, the activity will look in the view that was passed by `setContentView`, the layout that is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Your activity's layout is already inflated by using this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So if you call in activity:

```
TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.tv);
textView.setText("hello");
```

It will work cause the parent of this view if the activity's layout.
The thing you are doing in your ViewManager is inflating a new view which is not bind to any component.So where you suppose to show the text View.
This will be the solution:

```
 public void setText(String text){
    TextView textView=activity.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    textView.setText("hello");
}
```